# Enable Application Insights Azure Web App ARM Template

Tags: web-applications, azure-web-apps, azure-arm-template, application-insights

I successfully deployed **an app service plan, web application and application insights resources** using an **ARM Template**. The **APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY and APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING** app settings have been added to the configuration/app settings.

The issue im noticing is that when I select the 'application insights' option in the menu I'm presented with '**Turn on Application Insights**'. I thought adding the app settings above would turn on app insights but apparently not. Is it possible to **enable app insights in an ARM Template**? I'd like app insights to be ***enabled by default once the arm template deploys***.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by adding the additional application settings to my ARM template:

ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION: "~2" and
XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode: "default"

Once added application insights was turned on.

Comment: I tried this and your suggestions above and they did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

With these configuration settings in ARM Template, It can be done

> APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY= "yourappinsightinstrumentation_key"
> APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING="yourappinsights_connection_string"
> ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION: "~2"
> XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode: "default"